# Prevent Hibernate relation table from ever being audited

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I am using Envers for auditing and am trying to prevent an entity from ever being audited. If the entity is a part of a relation, like below, I want the FK field to be persisted on the related audit table (for `personId` on Receipt_Audit).

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "Receipt")
public class ReceiptModel {
  @Valid
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
  private PersonModel person;

  ...
}
```

The PersonModel is configured as follows:

```
@Entity
@Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
@Table(name = "Person")
public class PersonModel {
  ...
}
```

Persisting a Receipt works great with the configuration above. But, when trying to persist a Person, it blows up because no audit table exists for that entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want to do is to use the `@Audited(targetAuditMode=NOT_AUDITED)` on the actual relation inside `Receipt` and don't mark `Person` as audited.

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "Receipt")
public class ReceiptModel {
  @Valid
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
  private PersonModel person;
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class PersonModel {
}
```

Comment: I had a bug elsewhere in my code that made it seem like this was not working. This is absolutely the solution though, appreciate it mate.

Comment: For me "@NotAudited private PersonModel person" works